# Displaying Selected items on bootstrap 3 chosen

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-chosen

I am stuck at displaying the selected items after they are being saved into the database. Let's say I have selected 1and 2 in my bootstrap chosen, how to I display them?

Let's say I have this list:

```
<select id="selectNumbers" name="selectNumbers" class="chzn-select" data-placeholder="Choose numbers..." multiple="true" style="width:350px">
     <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
     <option value="3">3</option>
     <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

After selected and saved to database, how do I see the selected values when I come back to the screen again?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this http://jsbin.com/xugekaki/1 , chosen has multiple class to display multiple items.